# Linear Algebra in OpenCv

Tags: opencv

I'm a first year undergrad in computing science and took two calculus courses instead of having linear algebra as the other one. My question concerns the OpenCv and do I need to learn Linear Algebra first before I can effictively use it. If so, does it require the full linear algebra or just the basics (so then I could just go to the library).

Extra Info:
I joined an autonomous robotics team and they let me choose 3 options, robot vision, navigation, and simulation. I chose robot vision because it interest me alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short no, it does not require practical linear algebra knowledge. Calculus 2 would be more advantageous, even though linear algebra skills might come in handy. But in the end, most of the transform functions have been already created, for example the perspective transform just requires to be supplied two pairs of 4 points each: (A,B,C,D) that are assumed as forming another 4-point object (A',B',C',D'). you do zero of the calculations and get the end result anyway.

Comment: thanks exactly what I thought. The linear algebra stuff should'be abstracted at this point. But I'm curious how would caculus come in handy. What sort of problem will require this approach.

Comment: For example I've had to code a function calculating spatial differences (read: derivative approximations) in order to find regions in an image. Understanding what a derivative in 2D, and what a gradient is, has helped me facilitate this.